# HTTPS redirect loop for one folder rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect traffic in *one folder* using an apache2 .htaccess file that I've placed in `yourfolder`.  However, I'm getting a "This webpage has a redirect loop" whenever I visit that folder or subfolders.  Any idea why this isn't flying?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} yourfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/yourfolder/$1 [R,L]
```

EDIT:  Let me clarify, I'm trying to redirect `http://www.yourdomain.com/yourfolder` to `https://www.yourdomain.com/yourfolder`.

Comment: Why do you expect this should _not_ be a loop? You redirect from `yourfolder` to `yourfolder`.

Comment: because the incoming traffic is on 80, redirects to 443.  two different requests.

Comment: Indeed, that is correct. So as your own answer further down shows there must be very special circumstances for this to be a loop.

Comment: There was, a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I added a condition that checked if SSL was off, this works:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} yourfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/yourfolder/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is matching every page, including the one that you are trying to redirect the user to

Comment: Good point, I guess I don't have a mastery of these rewrite rules.  I'm trying to redirect `http://www.yourdomain.com/yourfolder` to `https://www.yourdomain.com/yourfolder`.

Comment: Try adding an exception, like: if not just "yourfolder", then redirect to https://www.yourdomain.com/yourfolder/$1